# gl.DrawElements seems to use incorrect indices

Tags: go, opengl

Consider the following code:

```
func makeVaoFromObj(obj *gwob.Obj) (uint32, uint32, uint32) {
    // Create VAO
    var vao uint32
    gl.GenVertexArrays(1, &vao)
    gl.BindVertexArray(vao)

    // Store coordinates in VBO
    var vbo uint32
    gl.GenBuffers(1, &vbo)
    gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
    gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * len(obj.Coord), gl.Ptr(obj.Coord), gl.STATIC_DRAW)

    // Vector
    gl.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, int32(obj.StrideSize), gl.PtrOffset(obj.StrideOffsetPosition))
    gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    // U,V Texture coordinate
    gl.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, int32(obj.StrideSize), gl.PtrOffset(obj.StrideOffsetTexture))
    gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(1)
    // Normals
    gl.VertexAttribPointer(2, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, int32(obj.StrideSize), gl.PtrOffset(obj.StrideOffsetNormal))
    gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(2)

    // Store indices of the coordinates in EBO
    var ebo uint32
    gl.GenBuffers(1, &ebo)
    gl.BindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo)
    gl.BufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * len(obj.Indices), gl.Ptr(obj.Indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW)

    return vao, vbo, ebo
}
```

This takes a loaded (blender) model and creates a VAO for it. I'm trying to draw this using `gl.DrawElements` function like this:

```
    gl.Clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    gl.BindVertexArray(m.vao)
    gl.UseProgram(program)
    # assumes we have 36 indices loaded
    gl.DrawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 36, gl.UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
```

But somehow I end up not with a cube (which it should be), but triangles all of them originating from a single point. I verified that the vertex coordinates loaded are correct and that the correct indices are loaded, but somehow I get a garbled model on my screen. Am I storing things incorrectly or not even at all?

[image: Triangles originating from a single point instead of a cube]

Funny thing is that when creating vertices and indices manually, it seems to work correctly. So I was thinking that something in the gwob library is wrong. But all the data from there seems to be correct too.

Comment: looks like some index offset is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue. It was because the gwobj library specifies indices as `int`, which are 64bit signed ints on my platform. With `drawElements` I specified `gl.UNSIGNED_INT` as type, which is an unsigned 32 bit integer.

Converting the indices array from `int` to `uint32` worked for me:

```
    // Convert indices from int to uint32
    uint32Indices := make([]uint32, len(obj.Indices))
    for i := range(obj.Indices) {
        uint32Indices[i] = uint32(obj.Indices[i])
    }
```